# ActiveRecord query : Placeholder not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, orm

I have a `Log` model with following columns:

```
"id"    "username"    "event"    "parameters"    "created_at"    "updated_at"
int      string       string      hstore           datetime        datetime
```

When I run

```
Log.sum( "(parameters -> 'starsAwarded' )::float" )
```

it works fine and gives the result. But when I try to use a placeholder in the following manner:

```
Log.sum( "(parameters -> ? )::float", "starsAwarded" )
```

It does not replace the placeholder with value. The query executed is:

```
SELECT SUM((parameters -> ? )::float) AS sum_id FROM "logs"
```

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I don't think `sum` supports placeholders as `where` does http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum

Comment: So, how do I pass variables so that I am not exposed to vulnerabilities?

Comment: Where are these variables coming from?